# Spring security Spring filter called twice to call external API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My application, Spring Boot, which uses Spring security 5.7, checks that incoming requests are authorized by verifying that the Authorization header is valid. To do this, I have to make a request to an external REST service by passing the header, because it is this service that handles authentication.

I wanted to make a filter that extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter, to take advantage of the Spring Security overlay, but there is a problem: the doFilter() method of the filter is called twice, and so the
authenticate() method of my AuthenticationManager, which creates two calls to the external api.

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .addFilter(filter())
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/login","/api/v1/user/password/reset-forgotten/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/status").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v3/api-docs").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .build();

    }

    public MyCustomAuthFilter filter() {
        MyCustomAuthFilter filter = new MyCustomAuthFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
                    throws AuthenticationException {
                String username = String.valueOf(authentication.getPrincipal());
                String authHeader = String.valueOf(authentication.getCredentials());
                try {
                    myExternalApi.checkUserToken(username,authHeader);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("");
                }
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                return authentication;
            }
        });
        return filter;
    }
```

```
public class MyCustomAuthFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

  @Override
  protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getHeader("Username");
  }

  @Override
  protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getHeader("Authorization");  }
}
```

So I tried to create a filter that extends OncePerRequestFilter and not AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter, but I lose the Spring Security overlay, and so it forces me to move away from the Spring Security features
(for example I can't do http.addFilter but http.addFilterBefore, I can't whitelist apis anymore with antMatchers("foo").permitAll())

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the securityFilterChain? Not adding `.addFilter(filter())`? I think it may be one of those extension that are added automagically by Spring so you actually add it manually "a second time" in the chain

Comment: Your custom filter is called with every request. Are you sure that only one request is processed? Maybe the preflight of CORS is executed, too.

Comment: is it a JWT token that you are checking?